# Application of Huber-White Variance Estimates in GLMER

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, robust-standard-error, sandwich

I'm currently working on an analysis in R using GLMER mixed-effects model with a logistic regression framework under the lme4 package. I would like to include empirical (Huber–White sandwich) variance estimates within the GLMER framework but I haven't been able to find a way to include them. I would greatly appreciate any assistance on addressing this issue.

Comment: With the mixed effects model you estimate the conditional effect, the sandwich variance is applied to marginal effects. They are applied to fundamentally different estimates.